# iron router reload specific header element

Tags: javascript, meteor, client-side, iron-router

I'm trying to reload a specific element in my Meteor app. I *am* new to Meteor, but I've at least gotten the client-side routing down to prevent reloading.

I'm basically trying to reload a small piece of text in the header, even though the header itself isn't reloading when the route changes.

Here's my router JS:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'PageLayout',
  yieldTemplates: {
    'Footer': {to: 'Footer'},
    'Header': {to: 'Header'}
  }
});
Router.route('/', {name: 'Home'});
Router.route('/about');
```

Here's my layout:

```
<template name="PageLayout">
  <header>
    {{> yield "Header"}}
  </header>

  <section id="page-container">
    {{> yield}}
  </section>

  <footer>
    {{> yield "Footer"}}
  </footer>
</template>
```

And here's basically what my header template looks like:

```
<template name="Header">
  <span>'{{text}}'</span> <!-- this is what I'm trying to change when the route changes -->
  <nav id="main-menu">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
  </nav>
</template>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want that header to reflect the current route name. Just make a template helper that returns it:

```
Template.Header.helpers({
  text: function(){
    return Router.current().route.getName();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out and let you know if it works. I kinda figured it may be something simple, but I was having a hard time coming up with anything in my searches. Also, is this how it's done in 1.2.1?  I saw something similar that used `Router.current().route`, but `Router.current()` kept returning `null`.

Comment: I'm accepting this because the example accomplishes what I wanted, but `Router.current()` keeps returning `null` for me. If I'm going to get the current route, I have to use `Iron.Location.get().path` instead. Thanks for helping a Meteor n00b like myself.

Comment: `Router.current().route.getName()` works in i-r 1.0.12

Comment: For me, `Router.current()` returns null for some reason... I'll try it in the helper, but the snippet I used instead is what I found as an alternative from another SO post.

Comment: Ok, so the one that wouldn't work for me before is working now... I guess the issue was that I was assuming `Router` would be set where I was originally trying to use it. And thanks for suggesting the `.getName()` method. The `.path()` method is the one I actually wanted in this case, but I'll probably be able to use the `.getName()` method elsewhere.